# Configure test double or allow messages. What's the difference in RSpec?

Tags: rspec

I have an rspec test with an instance double like written like this:

```
let(:ledger_instance) do
      instance_double(
        Workflow::Ledgers::ActiveRecordLedger,
        current_flow_name: current_flow_name,
        current_flow_completed?: false,
        completed_operations: completed_operations
      )
    end
```

Instead of those messages, I could also used `allow` to the same effect:

`allow(ledger_instance).to receive(:current_flow_completed?) { false }`

What's the difference between the two ways?